# How to disable ALL type checking in *.test.* files (including imported components)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

`"exclude": ["*.test.ts", "*.test.tsx"]` in tsconfig only prevents type checking of the test specific types (e.g. describe, it, expect, etc). I'm still seeing errors for imported Components within every test file in vscode. The only way to disable these imported component errors is with `//@ts-nocheck` at the start of every test file.

Is there a way to disable ALL type checking for all test files from the tsconfig, including any imported components from non-test files?

full `tsconfig.json` file (Create React App project)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["*.test.ts", "*.test.tsx"]
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: DID YOU FIND A SOLUTION???

Comment: Please see my main answer @Darvesh

Comment: Please see my main answer @DariusV

Answer (score 1):

I ended out going with the disable per file option listed in this other question

[How can I disable all typescript type checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506744/how-can-i-disable-all-typescript-type-checking)

If your tests are all in 1 folder you could try to exclude that folder, or go with disabling the .js file extension also listed in that thread.