# TypeScript: tsconfig allow anything

Tags: typescript

You read that right. I want TypeScript to allow ANYTHING. I have to use a library that's causing all sorts of ts errors when I compile the code that I can't seem to fix no matter what I've tried. I've been going through SO questions like these:

[TypeScript skipLibCheck still checking node_modules libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59906323/typescript-skiplibcheck-still-checking-node-modules-libs)

[Could not find a declaration file for module 'module-name'. '/path/to/module-name.js' implicitly has an 'any' type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292559/could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module-module-name-path-to-module-nam)

I have found a glimmer of hope. adding `"noImplicitAny": false` to my `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions` did get rid of the implicit any bugs. So now I'm wondering if there's a TS settings that will just allow anything. I know this is bad practice, but I just want my bundler to stop complaining and transpile my code. I don't care if I have a TypeScript file that passes a number to a function that only accept strings!

Comment: There's no simple config option to do this, see [ms/TS#29651](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29651) for the feature request.  You could [put `// @ts-nocheck` at the top of each file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#-ts-nocheck-in-typescript-files), or change your build to pipe the console output of tsc to `/dev/null` since it transpiles even if there are errors.  Does any of this constitute an answer for you? If so I can write it up; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: "change your build to pipe the console output of tsc to /dev/null". I am using rollup. Idk. The easiest solution would be to set all the `"no<whatever>"` to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

### Configuring TSConfig for type-checking

Disable the strict mode and all other relevant [type-checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) modes mentioned here in the docs. That should solve most of your problems, if that doesn't,

### Explicitly declaring Any

You can go on to assign any explicitly like this

```
let var: any = "string";
```

Comment: No, I have a library from npm that I can't modify, so I can't do this cuz git does not track node_modules

Comment: You can try using explicitly declaring any method as mentioned secondly

Comment: Where are you suggesting I make the changes? This still sounds like it's in the node_modules folder

Comment: I am suggesting them at the imports , when you import them and use them, you can Explicitly refer any

Answer (score 0):

Which npm Library are you using? often they come with built in type support.

For example `@types/node`(installed using `npm install @types/node`)... so `npm install @types/packageName`)