# Disable type checking from all .tsx files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typechecking, tsx

I'm trying to prevent type checking from my typescript project as it's still under development.
I tried adding `"checkJs": false` in my tsconfig file but still type checking triggers. Only solution i found was to add `// @ts-nocheck` in every file of my project. Is there a way to disable type checking without having to add `// @ts-nocheck` to every single file and instead use it in a single place.

my `tsconfig.json` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "checkJs": false,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "isolatedModules": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I would strongly advice you against turning type checking off. Even if it's under development, it's a huge help. You will introduce a lot of problems from an early stage.

Comment: I'm working on a exisiting project and it's giving out type check errors

Comment: So you're porting a js project to ts? Then I'd suggest keeping your js for a while, create definition files (*.d.ts) for what you need and one by one port to ts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506744/how-can-i-disable-all-typescript-type-checking

This can answer your question

Answer (score 1):

create `.eslintrc.js` in your root to ignore what you want or config your `eslint`. please read the [docs](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin), there are many rules in there. your case:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ["react-app", "plugin:prettier/recommended"],
  rules: {
     "@typescript-eslint/ban-ts-ignore": "off"
  },
  plugins: ["react", "@typescript-eslint", "prettier"]
};
```

to igore type check