# Try to share an array between two components in Angular

Tags: angular, input

I'm very new to Angular.
I try to share an Array of Tracks between two components, but I got an error. I use this decription
https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

```
  export class SpeakerComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    trackComponent = [];

    ...
  }


  export class TrackComponent implements OnInit {

   tracks: Track[]=[]
   ...
  }
```

In track.component.html
I got this error

**Error: src/app/component/track/track.component.html:1:15 - error TS2322: Type 'Track[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.**

```
 <app-speaker [trackComponent]=tracks></app-speaker>
```

Can anyone help?
thanks

Comment: Type your inputs `@Input() trackComponent: Track[] = []` or whatever the type is (it's unclear whether it should be typed `Track[]` or `TrackComponent[]`; I'd also change the name to be plural (`trackComponents`)).

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 option:

1. (Best Case)

```
      @Input()
      trackComponent: Array<Track> = [];
```

2. (Useless Case)

```
      @Input()
      trackComponent: Array<any> = [];
```

3. (Worts Case)
   Disable type check : [How can I disable all typescript type checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54506744/how-can-i-disable-all-typescript-type-checking)