# Starter tsconfig.json that is the most laxed/loose for pure javascript projects not using typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am having a pretty hard time finding a sample/starter tsconfig.json file that is the least strict/most laxed/loose options. I have a large javascript project and I'm really not interested fixing a ton of typescript errors, but, I want to allow my co-workers to write typescript if they want to to.

We are using create-react-app, so I can use this `TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR` flag to make it so typescript errors dont affect normal usage. ("When set to true, you can run and properly build TypeScript projects even if there are TypeScript type check errors. These errors are printed as warnings in the terminal and/or browser console.")

All I know so far is I want `allowJs: true` so typescript runs on .js/.jsx files.

So I want to enable typescript, but I want to start off with the smallest number of typescript errors+warnings. As we develop we can fix these issues we see, and gradually enable stricter options.

---

Update:
Found a similar question, not exactly the same but some may consider it a duplicate: [TypeScript - possible to disable type checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086843/typescript-possible-to-disable-type-checking)

I tried using this tsconfig.json file... it's an old one I had from few months ago, with several modifications:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5", // cra default
    "lib": [
      "es6", // old cra default?
      "dom", // cra default
      "dom.iterable", // cra default
      "esnext" // cra default
    ],
    "allowJs": true, // cra default
    "skipLibCheck": true, // cra default
    "esModuleInterop": true, // cra default
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true, // cra default
    "strict": false, // cra default
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, // cra default
    "module": "esnext", // cra default
    "moduleResolution": "node", // cra default
    "resolveJsonModule": true, // cra default
    "isolatedModules": true, // cra default
    "noEmit": true, // cra default
    "jsx": "react", // cra default

    "sourceMap": true, // old cra default?
    "checkJs": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": false, // old tsconfig was set to true
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false, // old tsconfig was set to true
    "strictNullChecks": false, // old tsconfig was set to true
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "types": ["jest"],

    "disableSizeLimit": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    "alwaysStrict": false, // default
    "newLine": "lf"
  },
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useBabel": true,
    "babelCore": "@babel/core"
  },
  "include": ["src"], // cra default
  "exclude": ["node_modules"] // from old tsconfig
}
```

I am bogged down with errors like this:

```
Property 'languageSettingString' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.  TS2339

    1602 |         action.data.data.account.locale !== state.locale
    1603 |       ) {
  > 1604 |         window.languageSettingString = action.data.data.account.locale
         |                ^
    1605 |         return {
    1606 |           ...state,
    1607 |           locale: action.data.data.account.locale,
```

And where I'm calling a redux action/prop thing like `this.props.setTaskValue`, I have this error... which is clearly in the same file in the redux `connect` call.

```
Property 'setTaskValue' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.ts(2339)
```

Comment: And.. asked about it here: https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/issues/99

Comment: Funny sidenote: 2 years later I am all over the opposite, a `strictest` config from tsconfig/bases

Comment: Got a nice reply from @orta on github:

Comment: orta: "Interesting, in many ways an empty tsconfig.json / jsonconfig.json is sort of the lower bounds for the strictness of a project. Which makes shipping a lax mode basically a NOOP I think."

Comment: orta: "Under the hood .ts files get the 'full' type checker, and .js files get a lot of simplifications - there's not really a way to make a .ts file get those .js files' laxness via a tsconfig entry"

Answer (score 1):

Here's my `tsconfig.strictest.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,

    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    /* Backwards compat flags */
    "noStrictGenericChecks": false,
    "suppressExcessPropertyErrors": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,

    /* Type Checking */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false
  }
}
```

You could flip all these to create a "loosest" config.

I'd encourage using this to start with:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  // You could toggle this between "strictest" and "loosest"
  // "extends": "./tsconfig.loosest.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "incremental": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

A very ideal option on top of this, is to track the state of typescript errors per-file with snapshots. A pre-commit hook could:

1. Run `yarn tsc --pretty --noEmit`
2. Breakup the errors per file
3. Store errors next to their as `Foo.tsx.terrs` ("type errors")

Comment: When you use the strictest config, half your code is going to exist just to satisfy the compiler 

Comment: Not half, just 5% of the code. You will spend extra time trying to make the compiler happy though. It's a two way street. You keep compiler happy, compiler keeps you happy.

Comment: I googled "tsconfig hard mode" and this came up. Thanks!!