# Disable TS2554 in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

How do I disable the TypeScript checking of `TS2554`? I want to utilize the dynamics of JavaScript in this manner for my project.

```
src/server.ts:14:1 - error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.

14 two('hello');
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/server.ts:10:19
    10 function two(one, two) {
                         ~~~
    An argument for 'two' was not provided.


Found 1 error.
```

Comment: Do you need to disable the type checking? Can't you make it an [optional parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript - possible to disable type checking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086843/typescript-possible-to-disable-type-checking)

Answer (score 0):

Make the second parameter optional. like below:

```
function two (one: string, two?: string) {
  ...
} 

two("hello")
```

Alternatively, You can use `@ts-ignore` in the line preceding an error to silence Typescript. or use `@ts-nocheck` at the start of the file.

```
@ts-ignore
two("hello")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use commented inline ignore `// @ts-ignore` to disable checks for an invocation:

```
// @ts-ignore
two("hello")
```