# create-react-app --template typescript — is it possible to temporarily disable type checking?

Tags: typescript, create-react-app, tsconfig

I'm working on a create-react-app with TypeScript and it auto-generates a tsconfig in my frontend folder with `"include": "/src"` every time I run the app, even if I delete the file or change it.

Is there a way  to disable type checking in a TS cra (without ejecting)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Disable type checking

**CRA uses Babel compiler**

[Babel](https://babeljs.io) is third part compiler for Flow, JSX and TypeScript with combining it. Babel **does not implement type checking**, CRA uses some methods from TypeScript Compiler and some of them from TSLint. So Babel can compile code even if there is a Type Error because Babel doesn't see it. Add this to the environment:
`TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true`

For more detail see [CRA documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/#)

**One file disabling**

Use `// @ts-nocheck` or `/* tslint:disable */` (depending on version of CRA) at the start of the file.

### Avoid to using type & using `any` type

Also, In TypeScript, types may be optional when defined that way. So you can't use it if you use in tsconfig.json

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       ///...
       "strict": false
   }
}
```

Since it seems like the biggest pain you are having is finding type definitions for external libraries, you can create an ambient definition for any variable you don't want to type checking for:

```
declare var variableName: any;
// better in .d.ts files
```

For example, for jQuery it would be `declare var $: any;`. Then you could do: `$("#test").myNonExistentFunction();` if you wanted.

Alternatively, when using es2015 modules the following code could be done to allow the library to be imported:

```
declare module "jquery" {
    var _temp: any;
    export = _temp;
}
```

**Shorthand ambient module declarations (TS 2.0+)**

In TS 2.0+, a better way to disable type checking for imports is to create a `.d.ts` file in your project and define shorthand ambient module declarations:

```
declare module "jquery";
// or use a wildcard
declare module "express-*"; // or use "*" to allow everything
```

This will allow you to use those imports freely without type checking:

```
import $ from "jquery";

$.something(); // ok at compile time, but will be an error at runtime
```

That said, the best path to take in this scenario is in a `.d.ts` file in your project to gradually define the interface of the library you're depending on based on what you use.

**ts-ignore comments (TS 2.6+)**

It's possible to disable any TypeScript error by using `// @ts-ignore` comments in TypeScript 2.6+. For example:

```
if (false) {
    // @ts-ignore: Unreachable code error
    console.log("hello");
}
```

**`@ts-expect-error` comment (TS 3.9)**
Expecting error is better, safer and more stable than ignore. Note that it works for next *code* line which means you can use comments between code and `@ts-expect-error`.

```
// @ts-expect-error
/* I will override error */
//
var num: string = 3;
```

No difference? Try to use this rules:

Pick `ts-expect-error` if:

- you’re writing test code where you actually want the type system to error on an operation
- you expect a fix to be coming in fairly quickly and you just need a quick workaround
- you’re in a reasonably-sized project with a proactive team that wants to remove suppression comments as soon affected code is valid again

Pick `ts-ignore` if:

- you have a larger project and new errors have appeared in code with no clear owner
- you are in the middle of an upgrade between two different versions of TypeScript, and a line of code errors in one version but not another.
- you honestly don’t have the time to decide which of these options is better.

---

Sources: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31089657/14724418, https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html