# my project has tsx and ts files, but I want to disable ts in test files

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs

I want to disable TS in my test files. The test files extension are of .test.tsx. I tried disabling TS check, but despite the code below, TS still complains.

```
"exclude": ["**/*.test.tsx", "**/*.test.ts"]
```

Does anyone know how to successfully disable TS in test.tsx? Is it wrong to use .tsx extension on files that I don't want to be checked by TS?

When I changed the extension to .js everything works as expected, but it's odd to suddenly introduce .js when every other file is ts related.

tsconfi.gjson

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "types": [
      "node",
      "@testing-library/jest-dom",
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["**/*.test.tsx", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean *"disable TS"*? If the compiler isn't turning that into JS, how can it _run_?

Comment: What's the goal of using TS then? Depending on your setup, it may be possible to disable type checks. *Is it wrong to use .tsx extension on files that I don't want to be checked by TS?* - yes, this defies the purpose.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want to disable type checking on .test.tsx files

Comment: @EstusFlask how can you disable type checks other than through _exclude_?

Comment: You didn't say anything about your setup, and this totally depends on it. For ts-jest there's https://huafu.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/diagnostics . But again, this doesn't make sense. If you're unable to fix TS  errors to the point TS is compilable then don't use it.

Comment: @EstusFlask right. I have CRA + typescript. I don't have ts-jest installed. I've updated my post to include tsconfig.json

Comment: This isn't solved with tsconfig. It matters how TS is being executed in the project. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65636853/create-react-app-template-typescript-is-it-possible-to-temporarily-disable-t , probably it's the case . I can't help further at this point. A proper way to do this is to use .jsx for untyped tests.